# Is it possible to communicate with I²C devices via the GPIO?

Tags: gpio, python, driver, i2c

Is it possible to communicate with I²C devices via the GPIOs?

Also, are there any existing drivers or libraries that make this possible from Python?

Answer (score 7):

According to the [wiki](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals#General_Purpose_Input.2FOutput_.28GPIO.29), I2C is exposed on pins 3 (SDA) and 5 (SCL).

#### Using from Python on Debian (Untested)

**Based on reading this [forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=3975&start=75).**

Run

```
sudo apt-get install python-smbus
```

to install the drivers. At the time of writing, there is a test script [here](http://www.frank-buss.de/io-expander/i2c-test.py).

> **Note**: Someone needs to test this.

Comment: "Someone needs to test this." When my RPi arrives, I'll test it.